# How to query on nested hash(3d level) for a column to be certain value?(in rails console)

Tags: ruby, hash

```
hash1 = {"k1" => "v1" , "hash2" => {"k2" => "v2", "hash3" => { "k3" =>"v3"}}}
```

How to I query on value of v3 to be certain value in rails console?

Comment: Are you given the key sequence `"hash2"`, `"hash3"`, `"k3"`? If not, are you asking if *any* nested hash in `hash1` has a value equal to a given value? Please clarify by editing.

Comment: We'd like to see what you tried. SO isn't a "give me code" site, it's a "help me fix my code" site. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) works for these cases:

```
{"k1" => "v1" , "hash2" => {"k2" => "v2", "hash3" => { "k3" =>"v3"}}}.dig('hash2', 'hash3', 'k3') 
# 'k3'
```

> It extracts the nested value specified by the sequence of key objects by 
>   calling dig at each step, returning nil if any intermediate step is
>   nil.

It doesn't matter if it's the Rails console or any other, as long as the Ruby version doesn't change and you're using the very same `Hash#dig` method.

Comment: We can't tell from the question if `dig` is necessary. It could be that `hash1["hash2"]["hash3"]["k3"]` is known to provide the desired value. In fact, one cannot tell from the question if any of the keys are even known.